# How to deploy imported VM on AWS from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, server-migration, ovf, ova

I have the following objects (file types shown) stored on an S3 bucket, which came from an export of an on-prem VM. How can I deploy them into an EC2 instance/AMI?

- vmdk
- nvram
- mf
- ovf

Online there is a lot of material on how to achieve this with an .ova file VM export. But been unable to find how to do it with the files I have.

Answer (score 0):

From [Importing a VM as an image using VM Import/Export - VM Import/Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html):

> After you have prepared your VM for export, you can export it from your virtualization environment. When importing a VM as an image, you can import disks in the following formats: Open Virtualization Archive (**OVA**), Virtual Machine Disk (**VMDK**), Virtual Hard Disk (**VHD/VHDX**), and raw.
> With some virtualization environments, you would export to Open Virtualization Format (**OVF**), which typically includes one or more **VMDK, VHD, or VHDX** files, and then package the files into an OVA file.

Comment: This only accepts format "ova" and "vmdk", what about all the other files (nvram, mf, ovf)?